# Read .xlsx as dataframe from minio response object

Tags: pandas, http, minio

I'm using Minio client to read object using the following code

```
timeout = timedelta(minutes=5).seconds
http_client = urllib3.PoolManager(
    timeout=urllib3.util.Timeout(connect=timeout, read=timeout),
    maxsize=10,
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
    ca_certs='/xxx/public.crt',
        retries=urllib3.Retry(
            total=5,
            backoff_factor=0.2,
            status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504]
        ))
client = Minio(endpoint='xxx',secure=True,access_key='xxx',secret_key='xxx', http_client=http_client)

response = client.get_object(
                bucket_name = 'bucket',
                object_name= 'file.xlsx'
            )
```

For which I get the response object

```
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse at 0x7fffdbf7cc50>
```

How can I read this reponse object as a dataframe in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

pandas_df = pd.read_excel(response.data)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).